# Listen for the Default Gateway IP Setting change event

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, dhcp

I have a [related question](https://superuser.com/q/602338/140891) over at Super User. The Default Gateway IP address on my laptop keeps changing on it's own and there doesn't seem to be a way to stop it. Is there a Windows API (or equivalent) that I can use to listen for the IP address change event and get to find out what program or computer is initiating the change?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for monitoring for IP changes, let alone an API to tell you what is initiating the change.  However, if you just want to detect when the Gateway IP changes, you can call `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` periodically, such as in a timer, locate the adapter you are interested in, and keep track of its current Gateway value so you can compare it over time.

Comment: There are actually several notification functions in the ip helper api, e.g. notifyipinterfacechange

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for the tip on NotifyIpInterfaceChange. It's available for Windows7 so I'll use it to try and figure out what is going on.